# Changing controls width inside a tableLayout panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, tablelayout

I am creating multi line text boxes and puttting it in a table layout panel:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();

tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
textbox1.Width = tableLayoutPanel1.Width - 100;
textbox1.Height = 150;
textbox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
```

As soon as I add the `Textbox` in `tableLayout` its width changes and its scroll get hidden behind the table layout scroll bars. I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0].SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0].Width=80;
```

Comment: I am confused. Is the textbox you are adding to the TableLayoutPanel named listBoxNewInput or is it not included in this code? Where is it added? Can you post the full code?

Comment: apologies, i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

When you set anchors, you let the table layout panel (TLP) rule the size of the textbox. To put the textbox in charge you have to tell the TLP to autosize rows and columns. That is: the row and the column where the textbox reside should have `SizeType` = `SizeType.AutoSize`.

I must admit, it is hard to manually code TLP's. I sometimes resort to peeping into a designer.cs file after shaping a TLP and child controls similar to what is going to happen dynamically.